# triangle block is not stretching full width

Tags: html, css

I have a question creating a long sharp triangle box on top of an image so that I create the effect that an image is cut off slightly. Like this:

[image]

I tried using the following CSS:

```
.overlay{
    background-image: linear-gradient(10deg, lightblue 50%, transparent 50%);   
    height: 165px;  
    width:100%;
}
```

See demo here: [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWPvZV)

But as you can see within the CodePen the blue square is not stretching to full width. I do not want to apply methods like rotating and stuff. Can anyone guide me into the right direction?

Comment: is this what you want? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/peyYVq

Comment: @ElmerDantas yes!! perfect. Thanks! at your solution then I can accept is as an answer

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: Put as answer as you suggested (and should be the accepted one..the other guy took my solution)

Comment: @ElmerDantas No worries! You got the accepted answer ;)

Comment: @ElmerDantas actually I didn't take your solution, I came up with my own which is better than yours as it has a smooth edge

Comment: @Rotan075 glad to help you! =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what you want

```
.overlay{
    background-image: linear-gradient(-2deg, lightblue 45%, transparent 45%);   
    height: 165px;  
  width:100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/peyYVq)

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to play around with the amount of degrees and the percentages in your gradient:

```css
.fixedheight {
  height: 590px;
  background-image: url(http://www.kaylainthecity.com/wp-content/uploads/gym.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relATIVE;
}

.overlay {
  POSITION: ABSOLUTE;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-3deg, lightblue 55%, transparent 56%);
  height: 165px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row fixedheight">
    <div class="pic"></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqpZjM)